# How to use aiobotocore for multiple concurrent downloads from s3?

Tags: boto3, python-asyncio, botocore

I am trying to pull multiple files from s3 using aiobotocore and boto's `get_object` method for s3. I want to make the requests concurrent and collect the results into one array at the end. How would I go about structuring my code? I can't find any examples of how to do this online. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Documentation is strikingly sparse, this question needs an example to demonstrate the correct structure. The most obvious questions that pop up are: do you create multiple sessions `aiobotocore.get_session(loop=loop)` or one? Same question for client, `session.create_client('s3')`.

Comment: See if these help https://github.com/research-bridge-partners/async_perf/blob/2cd7bb0ce3619f00f1dfa036f272ff07894c4eae/performance.py and https://github.com/MatejTuray/python_s3_benchmark/blob/26a91bbe436d408c462467962d39a5e9c1041a17/python_download_speed_check/download_asyncio.py

Comment: @DavidParks, did you find an answer to this?

Comment: These days I'm using `smart_open` and a simple multiprocessing pool. I'm able to read data from S3 at up to 2 GB/s on a dual 10 GbE node, and the code is quite simple. If you need to move the data from the workers to the main process you'll need to use System V shared memory and numpy (at least in my case) to avoid GIL lock. @vitalious